# Hidden <div> won´t get visible - with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have in my imported .css file a hidden :

```
   #firstname {
    visibility: hidden;
    }
```

In the header of the specific file where i want to show the div i have this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#firstname").style.visibility = 'visible';
    });
</script>
```

Jquery is also imported. Why won´t the div show up?

Edit: 
And the div´s id="firstname"

Comment: Should be seeing an error in browser console from that code. Have you looked at it?

Comment: Learn to debug! Learn to you your browser console. `Cannot read property 'visibility'` is probably sitting right there is plain sight in the log.

Comment: Won't even get to `Cannot read property` Error's out at `$(...).style is not a function`

Comment: This is not a CSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to use `$("#firstname").css("visibility", "visible");`

But before that - learn to search and also learn to debug - I'm pretty sure that there is an error in your browser console.